# Debian - VirtualBox - Failed to open the X11 display!

Tags: debian, x11, virtualbox

Running Debian 8 Jessie I installed VirtualBox but it fails to start.
No matter if I connect via PuTTY or locally on the machine, root or user, I always get the same error:

```
Failed to open the X11 display!
```

Following is set in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
X11Fowarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
```

Also, when connecting via PuTTY, X11 Forwarding is enabled and X display location set to `:0.0`

Xauth is installed, .Xauthority copied over to root too.

What could be wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does starting `xterm` for example work?

Comment: Can you please elaborate "fails to start"? What exactly happens when you try to start the OS without GUI?

Comment: @wurtel when trying to start `xterm` under user: `xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: xterm DISPLAY is not set`

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio I get the above mentioned error `Failed to open the X11 display!` when I type `virtualbox`. When OS starts I log in, there is no GUI, obviously.

Comment: So the problem is not with Virtualbox, your problem is displaying X remotely . You need to sort this out first. Or figure out how to configure and use Virtualbox without a GUI (which is certainly possible).

Comment: oh yea, you're right. X is the problem. the same error is same, locally or connecting remotely.
how can i solve the problem with X? any tips?

Comment: Run a X server first.